# Как выводить данные в начало JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот код [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3f5ukxj0/5/) Он выводит записи из Wikipedia, так вот результаты выводятся снизу вверх. Как сделать так, чтобы то, что там выводится внизу, выводилось вверху?

Я так понял, что дело в этой строке?

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
    $('#output').prepend("<li><a href=" + data[3][i] + ">" +  data[1][i] + "</a><p>" + data[2][i] + "</p></li>");
```

Comment: _prepend_ добавляет элемент в начало контейнера, _append_ - в конец

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i = data[1].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $('#output').prepend("<li><a href=" + data[3][i] + ">" +  data[1][i] + "</a><p>" + data[2][i] + "</p></li>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#output').append("<li><a href=" + data[3][i] + ">" +  data[1][i] + "</a><p>" + data[2][i] + "</p></li>");
```

Так?)